# How to implement deep clone function with type declarations?

Tags: typescript

This is the function what I try to implement with the generic type, but some error happend.

```
function cloneDeep<T> (data: T): T {
  const result= data instanceof Array ? [] : <T>{};

  for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result[key] = cloneDeep(value);  // error: Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'T | never[]'.
    } else {
      result[key] = value;  // error: Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'T | never[]'.
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Not completely resolved. I don't know how to deal with the Array type.

Comment: I don't see how that makes it different. A generic type can be an array type itself. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is used the generic type to wrap the entire value.

```
function cloneDeep<T> (data: T): T {
  const result = <T>(data instanceof Array ? [] : {});

  for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];

    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result[key] = cloneDeep(value);
    } else {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```